# onBackPressed() unfortunately app has stopped in android phone

Tags: android, soap

I am developing an eCommerce application where most of the java class file using Async Task for fetching data from server and I am using fragment in all java class . My problem is that when I click OnBackPressed it shows error in Async Task line because it takes some time interval again to fetch data from server..

MainActivity.java

```
package com.prashant;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {
    TextView txtView;
    private static MainActivity sMainActivity;
    ProgressBar prgLoading;
    RelativeLayout drawerPane;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    GridView lvNav;

    TextView Customer_name;
    TextView Customer_email;
    TextView Customer_mob;

    List<NavItem> listNavItems;
    List<Fragment> listFragment;
    private Boolean exit = false;

    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

    public int hot_number = Constants.ProductCart_Id.size();
    private TextView ui_hot = null;

    private boolean mNaviFirstHit = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sMainActivity = this;
        // Styling Action Bar
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(7,112,200)));


        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        //Getting Session Information Of Customer
        String MyPREFERENCES = "CustomerData";
        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences =getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        Constants.Customer_FirstName= sharedpreferences.getString("Customer_FirstName","");
        Constants.Customer_LastName=sharedpreferences.getString("Customer_LastName", "");
        Constants.Customer_MobileNo=sharedpreferences.getString("Customer_MobileNo", "");

        Constants.Customer_Id=sharedpreferences.getInt("Customer_Id", 0);
        Constants.Customer_Email=sharedpreferences.getString("Customer_Email", "");
        Customer_email.setText(Constants.Customer_Email);

        //Asigning FRagment names of sidebar
        listNavItems = new ArrayList<NavItem>();
        listNavItems.add(new NavItem("Home", null, R.drawable.pras));
        for(int i=0;i<Constants.Category_name.size();i++){
            listNavItems.add(new NavItem(Constants.Category_name.get(i),null,R.drawable.teju));
        }



        NavListAdapter navListAdapter = new NavListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item_nav_list, listNavItems);

        lvNav.setAdapter(navListAdapter);

        listFragment = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        listFragment.add(new MyHome());
        for(int i=0;i<Constants.Category_name.size();i++){
            listFragment.add(new ProductsListFragment());
        }
        listFragment.add(new MyHome());
        listFragment.add(new ActivityCart());
        listFragment.add(new LoginFragment());
        listFragment.add(new MyAbout());



        //Asigning FRagment names of sidebar

        //Saving fragment data as constants for my home categories
        Constants.listNavItems=listNavItems;
        Constants.listFragment=listFragment;
        //Saving fragment data as constants for my home categories

        //Load first fragment as default:
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_content, listFragment.get(0)).commit();

        setTitle(listNavItems.get(0).getTitle());
        lvNav.setItemChecked(0, true);
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerPane);



        // create listener for drawer layout
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open , R.string.drawer_close)
        {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
            {
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView)
            {
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }
        };

        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        final Menu mMenu = menu;
        MenuInflater mif = getMenuInflater();
        mif.inflate(R.menu.actionbar_icon_menu, menu);

        // Cart Icon in Action Bar
        final View menu_hotlist = menu.findItem(R.id.cart_icon).getActionView();
        ui_hot = (TextView) menu_hotlist.findViewById(R.id.hotlist_Cart_hot);
        updateHotCount(hot_number);

        menu_hotlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Constants.lastDetails = false;
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                ActivityCart cart = new ActivityCart();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_content, cart).commit();
                setTitle("Cart");
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerPane);
            }
        });




        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        if(actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
            return true;
        // Take appropriate action for each action item click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.cart_icon:
                // search action
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                ActivityCart cart = new ActivityCart();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_content, cart).commit();
                setTitle("Cart");
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerPane);
                return true;
              case R.id.action_search:

                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

  @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
       if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() >0) {
           getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
       } else {
           super.onBackPressed();
       }
   }




    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
        if (mNaviFirstHit) {
            mNaviFirstHit = false;
            return true;
        }
        else {
            if(itemPosition == 0)
                Constants.isCallParent = true;
            else
                Constants.isCallParent = false;

            Constants.SubCatposition = itemPosition;
            ProductsListFragment productsListFragment = new ProductsListFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_content, productsListFragment).commit();
            //lvNav.setItemChecked(position, true);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerPane);
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked at: " + itemPosition, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //mNaviFirstHit = true;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void setLoginDetails(){
        Customer_email.setText(Constants.Customer_Email);
        Customer_name.setText("Welcome, " + Constants.Customer_FirstName);
      Customer_name.setText(Constants.Customer_LastName);
    }
}
```

ProductListFragment.java

```
package com.prashant;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by prashant.
 */
public class ProductsListFragment extends Fragment {

    ProgressDialog pdialog;
    View v;
    Button sort,filter;
    //ListView list;
    GridView list;

    LazyImageLoadAdapter adapter;
    private static ProductsListFragment sProductsListFragment;

    // Title navigation Spinner data
    private ArrayList<SpinnerNavItem> navSpinner;

    // Navigation adapter
    private TitleNavigationAdapter titleNavigationAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         //((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(null);
         //((MainActivity)getActivity()).actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        // Action Bar
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,@Nullable ViewGroup container,@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.productlistfragment, container, false);
        sProductsListFragment = this;
        list=(GridView)v.findViewById(R.id.list);
       sort = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_sort);
        sort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),Pop.class));

            }
        });

        //clearData();
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(null);
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
      }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        Constants.cartEntry=0;

        //check Product Description fragment is called or not
        if (!Constants.lastDetails) {
            clearData();
            new getDataTask().execute();
        }
        else{
            String[] images=new String[Constants.Product_image.size()];
            images=Constants.Product_image.toArray(images);
            adapter = new LazyImageLoadAdapter(getActivity(), images);
            //Set adapter to listview
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            Constants.lastDetails = false;
        }


    }
    // clear arraylist variables before used
    void clearData(){
        Constants.Product_ID.clear();
        Constants.Product_name.clear();
        Constants.Product_price.clear();
        Constants.Product_image.clear();
        Constants.Product_qty.clear();
        Constants.Product_specialPrice.clear();
        Constants.Product_desc.clear();
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        // Remove adapter refference from list
        //list.setAdapter(null);
        //Refresh cache directory downloaded images
        //adapter.imageLoader.clearCache();
        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public View.OnClickListener listener=new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            //Refresh cache directory downloaded images
            adapter.imageLoader.clearCache();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    };


    public void onItemClick(int mPosition)
    {


      /*
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ProductDescription.class);
        intent.putExtra("descposition", mPosition);
        startActivity(intent);*/

        Constants.product_position = mPosition;
        ProductDescription productDescription=new ProductDescription();
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_content, productDescription, null).addToBackStack("productDescription").commit();
       //((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(Constants.Product_name.get(mPosition));
        getActivity().setTitle("Product Details");
    }

    // Image urls used in LazyImageLoadAdapter.java file

    public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            if (pdialog==null){
                pdialog=new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                pdialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                pdialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(getRetainInstance());
                pdialog.setCancelable(false);
                pdialog.show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // parse json data from server in background
            parseJSONData();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // Create custom adapter for listview
            String[] images=new String[Constants.Product_image.size()];
            images=Constants.Product_image.toArray(images);
            adapter = new LazyImageLoadAdapter(getActivity(), images);

            //Set adapter to listview
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

            if (!Constants.isSubCategory) {
                Constants.isSubCategory = true;
                // Spinner title navigation data
                navSpinner = new ArrayList<SpinnerNavItem>();
                navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem(Constants.Category_name.get(Constants.position - 1), R.drawable.icon));
                for (int i = 0; i < Constants.SubCategory_ID.size(); i++) {
                    navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem(Constants.SubCategory_name.get(i), R.drawable.icon));
                }

                // title drop down adapter
                titleNavigationAdapter = new TitleNavigationAdapter(getActivity(), navSpinner);
                // assigning the spinner navigation
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(titleNavigationAdapter, ((MainActivity) getActivity()));
            }

            if (pdialog.isShowing()){
                pdialog.dismiss();
                pdialog=null;
            }

            if (Constants.Product_ID.isEmpty()){
               // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No products found!!Check your internet connection!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setTitle("No Product Found!!").setMessage("Slow Internet/Check Your Internet Settings").create().show();
            }

            /*for (int i = 0; i < Constants.Product_ID.size(); i++) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "__" + Constants.Product_ID.get(i) + "__" + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }*/
            // if internet connection and data available show data on list
            // otherwise, show alert text

        }
    }

    // method to parse json data from server
    public void parseJSONData(){

       SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Constants.NAMESPACE, "catalogCategoryAssignedProducts");
            String Catid;
            // add paramaters and values
            request.addProperty("sessionId", Constants.sessionId);
            if ((!Constants.isSubCategory) || Constants.isCallParent) {
                Constants.isCallParent = false;
                request.addProperty("categoryId", String.valueOf(Constants.Category_ID.get(Constants.position - 1)));
                Catid=String.valueOf(Constants.Category_ID.get(Constants.position - 1));
            }
            else {
                request.addProperty("categoryId", String.valueOf(Constants.SubCategory_ID.get(Constants.SubCatposition - 1)));
                Catid=String.valueOf(Constants.SubCategory_ID.get(Constants.SubCatposition - 1));
            }

        api_calls call=new api_calls();
        call.getCategoryProducts(Catid);


            if (!Constants.isSubCategory) {
                Constants.SubCategory_ID.clear();
                Constants.SubCategory_name.clear();
                parseJSONDataSubCategory();
            }


    }

    // method to parse json data from server
    public void parseJSONDataSubCategory(){

        try {


            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Constants.NAMESPACE, "catalogCategoryTree");

            // add paramaters and values
            request.addProperty("sessionId", Constants.sessionId);
            request.addProperty("parentId", Constants.Category_ID.get(Constants.position-1));
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            //Web method call
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(Constants.URL);
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
            androidHttpTransport.call("", envelope);
            //get the response
            SoapObject result2 = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
            SoapObject pii2 = (SoapObject) result2.getProperty(5);
            for (int i = 0; i < pii2.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
                //JSONObject object = data.getJSONObject(i);
                SoapObject pii = (SoapObject)pii2.getProperty(i);
                //JSONObject category = object.getJSONObject("Category");
                Constants.SubCategory_ID.add(Long.parseLong(pii.getProperty(0).toString()));
                Constants.SubCategory_name.add(pii.getProperty(2).toString());
            }


        }  catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Making Sub Drawer for Sub Category
    public static ProductsListFragment getInstance() {
        return sProductsListFragment;
    }
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.popBackStack();
    }

}
```

Logcat

```
02-11 12:39:57.838 12954-14579/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
                                                   Process: com.softonetech.www.takenick, PID: 12954
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1
                                                       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:310)
                                                       at com.prashant.ProductsListFragment.parseJSONData(ProductsListFragment.java:250)
                                                       at com.prashant.ProductsListFragment$getDataTask.doInBackground(ProductsListFragment.java:185)
                                                       at com.prashant.ProductsListFragment$getDataTask.doInBackground(ProductsListFragment.java:167)
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: please share your log

Comment: what the error are you getting? log please

Comment: I share my log please check that

Comment: request.addProperty("parentId", Constants.Category_ID.get(Constants.position-1));
error seems related to this line because it try to get -1 position and it then you get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException

Answer (score 1):

try cancelling your Async task execution during `onBackPressed()`

Declare:

```
Public getDataTask asyncFetchData;

 asyncFetchData = new getDataTask();
 asyncFetchData.execute();
```

Now in your Fragment:

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        getView().requestFocus();
        getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                        if (asyncFetchData!= null)
                            asyncFetchData.cancel(true);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Back pressed...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Also in `doInBackground` notify the `AsyncTask` to cancel execution

```
 @Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // parse json data from server in background
    parseJSONData();
    if (isCancelled()) break;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: break outside switch or loop this message shows on break;  and onKeyDown is never used.